# Evento keydown com delay quando mantenho o botão pressionado

Tags: jquery

estou criando um pong usando JQuery e estou com problema no evento keydown . Eu vou controlar o jogador um pelas seta cima e baixo, porém quando eu mantenho o botão pressionado, ele tem um delay entre a primeira e a segunda execução.

JS:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 38:
          if ((topPlayerOne - 10) >= 0) {
            topPlayerOne = (topPlayerOne - 10);
            playerOne.css('top', topPlayerOne);
          }
        break;
        case 40:
          if ((topPlayerOne + 10) <= 170) {
            topPlayerOne = (topPlayerOne + 10);
            playerOne.css('top', topPlayerOne);
          }
        break;
        default: return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pongTable">
  <div id="playerOne" class="player"></div>
  <div id="playerAI" class="player"/></div>
</div>

<div id="score">
  <div id="scorePlayerOne" class="score">0</div>
  <div id="scorePlayerAI" class="score">0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dessa forma não vai dar certo mesmo, o evento `keydown` só é disparado uma vez quando você pressiona a tecla.

Por conveniência, o seu sistema operacional possui esse mecanismo que ao se segurar pressionado algumas teclas, ele simula a tecla sendo pressionada várias vezes em seguida, mas essa não é a forma certa de se trabalhar num jogo.

Você provavelmente deveria utilizar a abordagem clássica dos video games, e criar um loop principal que é executado 30 ou 60 vezes por segundo. Nesse loop você verifica quais teclas estão pressionadas, e faz o tratamento de acordo.

Por exemplo:

```js
// objeto contendo as teclas pressionadas
const keys = {
  up: false,
  down: false
}

// listener que captura quando as teclas são pressionadas
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch(e.which) {
    case 38:
      keys.up = true;
      break;
    case 40:
      keys.down = true;
      break;
    }
})

// listener que captura quando as teclas são liberadas
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  switch(e.which) {
    case 38:
      keys.up = false;
      break;
    case 40:
      keys.down = false;
      break;
    }
})

// loop principal do jogo
function mainLoop() {
  console.clear();

  if (keys.up) {
    // código para mover o jogador para cima aqui
    console.log('up')
  } else if (keys.down) {
    // código para mover o jogador para baixo aqui
    console.log('down')
  } else {
    // nenhuma tecla pressionada
    console.log('neutral')
  }
}

// invoca o loop principal a cada 15 milesimos
setInterval(mainLoop, 15)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```